# Fan light won't turn on

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch, light

I have a fan with a light. It's controlled by a single pole dimmer. Recently the light stopped working. The bulb is fine (works in a lamp), and the pull chain is fine (just replaced it recently). What's odd is that the fan works, even when the dimmer switch is completely off. When the switch is on, and I pull the pull chain, the light flashes on quickly but then remains off. Anyone know what's going on here? My original thought was a bad dimmer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What kind of lightbulb is it?  Is it compatible with a dimmer?

Comment: It's a standard 40W, 120V bulb. It was working with the dimmer before last week.

Answer (score 0):

See Tyson. The only other thing that bothers me is that you said you replaced the switch recently. Did everything work fine before you replaced the switch? Also you said the fan and light is controlled by one dimmer.

Are you saying the fan and the light only work when the dimmer is on or off? Because if that is what you are saying then I am not surprised. Fans do not work off of dimmers. They work only on a switch or a fan speed controller. Lights do not work on fan speed controller. They work on a switch or a dimmer. So if what I just said is true, then something is probably failed in the fan and the whole thing would need to be replaced and installed properly.

Also the reason why Tyson is asking his question is because different dimmers are need for incandescent vs CFL vs LED, and they react different to allowable dimmer types. Example: some may only go to 50% dimming then off.

If everything I have just written is not true expect the light stopped working then open up the mounting between the fan and Light kit and make sure everything is plugged in and none of the wiring is loose or broken. Open the fan hanger cover and make sure of the same there. Look for a blue or red wire not connected. Should be labeled "light".

Keep us posted.

Comment: Yes, everything worked fine before I replaced the switch. As I responded to Tyson, it was a standard light bulb.

Answer (score 0):

Watt limiters can cause the light not to work, these do go bad and have caused quite a few fans to be tossed in the trash. There are 2 types that I have seen, 2 wire easy to bypass with a wire nut (just to verify it is bad of corse) There is a 3 wire that on that type the ones I have worked on had a hot, output and neutral. Tie the hot and output together and cap the neutral it was for the electronics to detect the load 190 watts or less. Of course this information is just for testing and being able to take the failed part in to get a replacement. We would never want to bypass DOE rules, however removing the limited affects the UL listing, but my UL stickers did not burst into flames and I had just converted to LED lamps when they failed. Have worked fine ever since ,,,,, hmmm did that new part ever get ordered?
That's my experiances with lights not working on fans other than the switch itself but you understand how the switch works from the post and foment.